# sequence with 4 multiple difference of previous two values

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

[image]

tried the first few terms, they are
0, 4, 16, 48, 128, 320, 768, 1792, 4096, ...
but can't figure out the general pattern behind it. Is there a general formula for $a_{n}$ in terms of n? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

We need to solve the recurrence $$a_n - 4a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2} = 0$$ with initial conditions $a_1 = 0,a_2=4$.

Let's proposed $a_n = r^n$ and substitute, we get
$$
0 = r^n - 4r^{n-1} + 4r^{n-2} = r^{n-2} \left[r^2 - 4r +4\right]
  = r^{n-2}(r-2)^2
$$
So $a_n = 2^n (A + Bn)$ for constants $A,B \in\mathbb{R}$. PLug in the initial conditions.